# Why do most sites display male related ads only?

Tags: website-design

Ads like Hot girls wearing Bra showing **click me** to remove bra.

Another Ads shows If you play this game you will get addicted to it (Hot Girl posing on this Ad).

You can simply say male related ads only. Why so?

Answer (score 6):

Two reasons:

- you visit porn sites
- male targeted ads probably generate better profit than female targeted ads.

Comment: I haven't seen the "Click Me" ads. I would have noticed those   :) So I think you're correct with the first bullet point.